# How it works: Htaccess Rewrite Engine?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^mangas/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^mangas/([^/]+)/$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^mangas(/?)$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(/?)$ index.php?manga=$1&chapter=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/?)$ index.php?manga=$1 [L]
```

But what happens is when you go to the link like the following: `/manga/name_of_manga` It gives me a 404 not found error. Is the htaccess file not rewriting the `index.php?manga=$1` into this: `/manga/name_of_manga` ?

Basically, anything that is in the form of `index.php?manga=$1` is converted just to `/manga/name_of_manga` and it should still display stuff. If I go directly using the index.php method, it works fine.

For example, these work:

`http://neoblizz.net/manga/?manga=Tower%20of%20God`

`http://neoblizz.net/manga/index.php?manga=Tower%20of%20God`

These don't:

`http://neoblizz.net/manga/Tower_of_God/`

`http://neoblizz.net/manga/Tower%20of%20God/`

```
154.20.109.65 - - [03/Jul/2014:18:28:50 -0400] "GET /manga/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - neoblizz.net "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "-"
154.20.109.65 - - [03/Jul/2014:18:28:51 -0400] "GET /manga/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - neoblizz.net "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "-"
154.20.109.65 - - [03/Jul/2014:18:28:52 -0400] "GET /manga/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - neoblizz.net "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "-"
154.20.109.65 - - [03/Jul/2014:18:28:52 -0400] "GET /manga/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - neoblizz.net "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Is this in `/comic/` directory?

Comment: Yes. It is in `/comic/`.

Comment: @anubhava Added an example with links.

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /manga/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^mangas/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^mangas/([^/]+)/?$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^mangas/?$ - [F,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?comic=$1&chapter=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?comic=$1&chapter=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?comic=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Internal server error now, other links don't work either (ones that were working before).

Comment: can you explain what might be the cause?

Comment: Oh there was a typo, fixed now. Can you try again?

Comment: I tried with that too, typo was `/manga/` not `/mangas/` also, all the comic in Rewrite rule are manga. But didn't work. This is really frustrating as another site of mine uses same settings and is working just fine.

Comment: Once you figure out your real names this is pretty basic stuff in rewrite and it worked in my tests. Better you provide specifics like what is location of this .htaccess? What URL didn't work? What error do you see etc?

Comment: I have provided the URL in the first post under edit. There was a 500 and 404 error after your edit, before it was just 404 after I select the manga. http://neoblizz.net/manga/ I am placing htaccess in manga folder. Directory is such: manga contains mangas and index.php which runs all this.

Comment: Visiting just `/manga/` will present content from `/manga/index.php` I created directory structure exactly as you say and copy/pasted this whole code in `/manga/.htaccess` but I didn't get any 500. For which URL in your browser do you get 500? Are there any other .htaccess OR any other rules?

Comment: I get 500 and 404 for anything inside `http://neoblizz.net/manga/` and there are no other htaccess or rules. just the one you provided me. Should I post the index and function files too? They're long though.

Comment: Since everything is working fine using exact same setup you will need to provide me Apache error.log when 500 shows up.

Comment: http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/explanation-of-500-errors-a595888.html do you think this could be the cause? And I don't think I have access to the error.log. It is a shared server, I do have access to ftp and access logs.

Comment: If that is the case I understand, but the link shows us that aside from 500 there is also a 404 error. Which means with the new htaccess the old problem isn't resolved yet. @anubhava I really appreciate your help, I have been frustrated over this for a long time now. Lol.

Comment: Everybody has read only access to error log and since this code is working fine I cannot proceed further without seeing cause of 500 error on your side.

Comment: Sorry for such a delay, but that is what I found from the log. I have edited the main post with it.

Comment: Also I found out `RewriteBase /manga/` gives HTTP 500 error. Removing it fixes the first page.

Comment: What you are showing here is access.log but I like to see error.log snippet for 500 error

Comment: Also above .htaccess is supposed to be placed in `/manga/.htaccess` not in `DocumentRoot`

Comment: I asked 1&1 for error log, I don't even have read permission to access those, or maybe I don't know how to. Lol. And yes, I placed it in manga directory.